# Milky quartz stones give off odour after being struck - persistent tribo-odorosity(?)

Tags: experimental-physics, education

I have these white stones that give off a strong sulphur-like smell when struck together to produce a spark (triboluminescence). This is mostly due to hydrogen sulphide as suggested by many sources such as:
https://www.mineralseducationcoalition.org/sites/default/files/scratch_sniff_minerals_0.pdf

> By  the  way,  I’ve  also  noticed  that  some  water-rounded  white 
>   quartz  pebbles  sold  as landscaping rocks will, when knocked
>   together, give off a sulfurous odor.  This is probably due to a slight
>   amount of hydrogen sulfide in their fluid inclusions, too.

The smell persists for a few minutes after the stones are struck together. Obviously, the trapped gas is released from the gaps in the silica crystallites but why the odour lingers is puzzling. Is it because $H_2S$ is more viscous than air that it stays near the surface of the stones? Or is it adsorption of the gas on the surface? Or both? Or a different mechanism?

I want to develop this as an inquiry question for school students as it is something very tactile that involves many physical concepts.

Comment: Would the properties of a chemical such as hydrogen sulphide be better known on ChemistrySE,  thereby increasing your chances of a good answer?

Comment: While the problem is "tactile", it's completely impossible for students to "solve" this problem. The identification of the smell, alone, would require serious chemistry knowledge and research. Statements like "probably due to" are guessing, not scientific inquiry. Since a primary analysis of the kind that would be performed by a chemist in a lab is outside of the reach of your students, I would suggest to give them access to an SO2 test kit: http://www.northernbrewer.com/quick-test-free-so2-10-test-kit. If the test indicates the presence of the gas, then we have something resembling science.